# ¿Que más necesito para poder almacenar la sesión en un cache de redis?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-redis

Ya instale la librería de `RedisSessionStateProvider` y su dependencia `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName`, también coloque la configuración en el `web.config`

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionProvider" cookieless="true" >
   <providers>
      <add name="RedisSessionProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" port="6380" host="XXX.redis.cache.windows.net" accessKey="OQm………15E=" ssl="true" connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="1000" retryTimeoutInMilliseconds="3000" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true" />

 </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Pero no logró que se almacene la sesión en [redis](/questions/tagged/redis), pero si realizo la conexión en código la conexión es exitosa, aquí está mi código:

```
/// se crea la conexión
private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
{
    var redisOption = new ConfigurationOptions();
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("XXX.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password=OQmAPmp0 . . . . TJE15E=");
});


///regresa el objeto de la conexion

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
{
    get
    {
        return lazyConnection.Value;
    }
} 

///creo la session y agrego elementos manualmente al redis       
public ActionResult SessionStart()
{
    IDatabase cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
    Session["loginTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    string strValue = "myvalue";
    Session.Add("myvalue ", strValue);
    return View();
}
```

Por ejemplo lo que agrego manualmente se almacena exitosamente pero sí creo una sesión no se almacena en automático, creo necesito algo mas pero no que es.

Comment: Pero si asignas un valor a la Session este no se relacion con el cache de redis, van por separado. La idea es que dejes de usar el objeto Session y uses el cache de redis para guardar datos que trabajen de forma distribuida

Comment: Deja ver si entendí, lo que necesito es almacenar la sesion o las variables que necesite de forma independiente en el cache de redis?, Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Si quieres trabajar con un medio de persistencia distribuido, debes dejar de usar el objeto Session y usar unicamente el cache de redis. Es alli donde deberias asignar los datos que quieras persistir, puedes ponerle alguna key por usuario para separar los datos

Comment: Sino el otro camino es configurar el objeto Session para que use una base de datos  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akshayns/archive/2008/10/04/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-store-a-session-state.aspx  de esta forma hacer que la Session funcione en un sistema distribuido

Comment: Te fijaste si tu app se está conectando correctamente a Redis?
@LeandroTuttini lo que está intentando hacer es exactamente lo mismo que con una base de datos, pero con Redis como medio de almacenamiento.

Comment: En un principio estaba utilizando este ultimo recurso pero me encontré con problemas de compatibilidad, pues estoy trabajando en Azure donde esta mi base de datos. esto es lo que estoy tratando de hacer: https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/

Comment: No hay información suficiente, pero por lo que colocas en el post me atrevería a decir que no estas en un proyecto de ASP.Net, o si?

Comment: O si estoy trabajando en asp.net mvc 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acabo de hacerlo desde mi propio proyecto sin problemas, utiliza este código para probarlo en tu ambiente. Te recomiendo que lo pruebes en un proyecto en limpio, puede que tengas algo mal en tu web.config que no esté permitiendo cargar el provider y no lo hayas notado

## web.config

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore" >
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore"
         type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
         host="abcde1234.redis.cache.windows.net"
         accessKey="FuDmzfO3B/6M1cX1ls="
         ssl="true" throwOnError="true" port="6380" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true"
         databaseId = "1"
         />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

y tan solo con esto en mi home controller (o el que quieras)

## HomeController/Index

```
Session["test-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()] = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
```

Para verificar los valores uso [Redis Desktop Manager](http://redisdesktop.com/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, deja lo hago y te platico como me fue

Comment: Si tines razon  algo andaba mal en mi web config o en las librerías de redis porque las desinstalé  y las volví a instalar de nuevo  y funcionó  además de terminar por completo el post ya qué  no lo estaba terminado  debido a que no veía  que se modificará el caché de redis y paraba la ejecución de mi localhost. Aún así me fue de mucha utilidad tú ayuda y de las demás personas. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria seguir guias como esta

[How to Use Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/)

para implementar redis integrado en tu aplciacion que publiques en azure. Despues de seguir esa guia si continuas con problemas se podria analizar, pero partimos de una base que has implementado.

Analizando un poco mas en profundidad puedo ver una implementacion que configura el session state usando redis

[ASP.NET Session State Provider for Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-asp.net-session-state-provider/)

La verdad siempre habia visto a redis usandose como objetos del propio cache o en union a un orm como ser entity framework, pero veo que tambien puede reemplazar los objetos de asp.net

saludos

Comment: Si esa es la guía que he utilizado ya para crear el cache de Redis y hacer algunas pruebas con valores agregados manualmente, seguiré buscando mas información y gracias!

Comment: ahh bien si has seguido esa guia ya tenemos donde partir, en que punto es que encuentras problemas?  Imagino entiendes que el objeto Session ya no debes usar en Azure (salvo como comente antes que lo configures a Sql Server), entonces si solo usarias redis

Comment: Asi es, yo lo que quiero es almacenar datos de session de un usuario en el cache de redis, pero yo estaba en la creencia de que se hacia en automatico como lo hace el session state en modo SQLServer y me llevo la sorpresa de que no es asi o algo me falta para poder almacenar los datos

Comment: me temo que no hay automatico, el objeto session de asp.net las dejas de lado y pasas a usar las api de redis, justamente estas son las que incluye la libreria que referencia con nuget